# How to run scene builder standalone in Debian

Tags: javafx, debian

As I can understand if I use Jessie I can install deb openjfx from rep and use scene builder. But how to run it in a standalone mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is slightly unclear, if you mean you want to create a standalone application of scene builder from the debian package (.deb) you can try some of the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106183/how-do-i-create-stand-alone-packages-from-ubuntu-repository) . However its worth noting the application may have dependencies upon other applications that the .deb usually installs.

However, you can actually download a version of scene builder [here](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/)
directly as a jar file and simply run it by using

```
java -jar SceneBuilder-8.2.0.jar
```

Hope this helps and good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you! Last time I have downloaded it, it had been on Oracle website.